# updating totals with one sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, profiles

I have a table with players, and a table with profiles. Profiles(users) can "claim" players, so that the "profile" field in a player record gets set to the id of the profile.

I want a totalscore property(which contains the sum of all previous score values) in my profiles table. To calculate data commited in the past, i've written the following query:

```
UPDATE profiles,players
SET profiles.`totalscore` = profiles.`totalscore` + players.`score`
WHERE players.`profile`=profiles.`id`
```

However, totalscore gets set to the last found value. How would i solve this?

Comment: Please, provide sample input data and desired result (now it's not clear)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use group by.

```
UPDATE profiles
inner join (
select profileid,SUM(score) as playersscore
from players
group by
profileid) players
ON players.profileid=profiles.id
SET profiles.totalscore = profiles.totalscore + playersscore
```

Comment: result: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY profiles.`id`' at line 4